# For $X$ a quasi-projective variety, when does there exist a nonzero map $\mathcal O_X(1) \to \mathcal O_X$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

In light of the comments below, I suppose this is really several questions. Let $X$ be a quasi-projective variety. I would like to know what can be said about $X$ in each of the following situations. Conversely, I would be interested in conditions weaker than the ones noted below which guarantee one of the following properties.

1. $\mathcal O_X$ is ample.
2. $X$ admits an ample line bundle $\mathcal L$ such that $H^0(\mathcal L^{-1}) \neq 0$.

Note that (1), and *a fortiori* (2), holds when $X$ is affine.

3. $X$ admits an ample line bundle $\mathcal L$ such that $H^0(\mathcal L^{-1}) = 0$.
4. For any ample line bundle $\mathcal L$ on $X$, $H^0(\mathcal L^{-1}) = 0$ (the negation of (2)).

Note that (4), and *a fortiori* (3), holds when $X$ is projective.

If $X$ is an open subscheme of a normal $\bar X$ which has any of the above properties, and if the codimension of the complement $\bar X \setminus X$ is $\geq 2$, then by Hartog's lemma, $X$ inherits the property.

Comment: What is a variety? If you allow nilpotents there are examples which are projective of positive dimension, such as the curve $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ with homogeneous equations $xz^2=yw^2$, $x^2=y^2=0$. You get a nonzero section of $\mathscr{O}_C(-1)$, defined to be $xw^{-2}$ if $w≠0$ and $yz^{-2}$ if $z≠0$. The first equation of $C$ guarantees that they coincide if $zw≠0$, and $C$ is supported on the $(z,w)$-projective line, hence $z$ and $w$ cannot vanish simultaneously.

Comment: Very interesting! I'm most interested in the most classical case -- a reduced, irreducible, locally closed subscheme of $\mathbb P^n$.

Comment: The complement of a 1-codimensional closed subvariety need not be quasi-affine: consider $X=\mathbb{A}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\subset\overline{X}=\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Wow, thanks for setting me straight! The argument I had in mind was wrong. This invalidates most of my discussion in the question statement, but leaves the question open...

Comment: It is possible that no such isomorphism exists even if $X$ is affine ! Let $E$ be an elliptic curve, $P\in E$ be a point and $X=E\setminus P$. Let $L$ be a very ample line bundle on $E$ that is not of the form $\mathcal{O}_E(nP)$ for some $n>0$. Then there is no isomorphism $L|_X\simeq \mathcal{O}_X$.